# How to Pass test.isRunningTest() Condition in Test Class

Tags: code-coverage

How to Cover test.isRunningTest() in test class in if else conditon

```
for(String ownerId : ownerIds){
            if(loggedInUsers != NULL && loggedInUsers.size() > 0){
                String a;
                if(test.isRunningTest() == true){
                     a = null;
                    System.debug(a);
                }else{
                     a = ownerId;
                    System.debug(a);
                }
```

Comment: Quick note: `test.isRunningTest()` returns a boolean, so your if statement evaluates to either `if(true == true)` or `if(false == true)`. The equality check doesn't have any purpose here, so you can simplify to just `if(test.isRunningTest())`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't cover the else statement directly, because Test.isRunningTest() will always return true, so you'll never reach the else block. There's lots of ways to work around this. The most simple way is to place the else before the if:

```
for(String ownerId : ownerIds){
    if(loggedInUsers != NULL && loggedInUsers.size() > 0){
        String a = ownerid;
        if(test.isRunningTest()){
             a = null;
        }
        System.debug(a);
    }
}
```

For such a short statement, you could also get code coverage via a ternary operator:

```
String a = Test.isRunningTest()? null: ownerid;
```

However, a **proper** solution is to fix your test so the Test.isRunningTest() is not necessary at all (and this is almost always true!).

Answer (score 4):

The code will always follow the `test.isRunningTest() == true` branch in a test so you cannot cover the `else` branch. If you genuinely need to vary how the code works in test and in normal use with this sort of `if/else` logic then you will not be able to achieve 100% code coverage.

But the main point of tests is to confirm the behaviour of the code with coverage only being an indicator that you are making progress towards that goal. So a bit below 100% is not in itself a *real* problem.

Obviously best to keep `test.isRunningTest()` branches to an absolute minimum.

Answer (score 3):

You just don't cover it, that is the whole point of having the Test.isRunningTest() thing. You should avoid it when not needed. Most cases you may need it is sending emails from apex or doing any sort of integration, so you can mock the call.